# Unable to install TensorFlow with miniconda on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, tensorflow, miniconda, macos-monterey

I tried to install tensorflow following this issue: https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153

Although for M1 Monterey the wheel is not working and showing the following error.

```
pip install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl

ERROR: tensorflow_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Looking for the updated wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to Install TensorFlow successfully

1. Download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) or the smaller [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).
2. On macOS or Linux open a terminal window. Use the default bash shell on macOS or Linux.
3. Choose a name for your TensorFlow environment, such as “tf”.

To install the current release of CPU-only TensorFlow, recommended for beginners:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

Or, to install the current release of GPU

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

For more details, please check [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) link.